# Error at form: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, flask

I am getting this problem on specific form and rest of the Python/Flask project is working fine. I am using Pycharm and my code is set to utf-8 in IDE. Don't know how to manage this. There is a form and its getting input value from list like below:

```
my_school = form.university.data
            waiverlist = ['Alpha University', 'Beta College', 'Charlie University', 'Foxthroat International University']
            if my_school in waiverlist:
                package = Package(
                    student_id=profile_data.id,
                    stripe_id = 'N/A For non-stripe users',
                    student_email= profile_data.email,
                    is_active=True,
                    package_type='PartnerSubscription',
                    subscription_id='N/A For non-stripe users'
                    )
                dbase.session.add(package)
                dbase.session.commit()
```

In my template I have:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">

                            {{ form.university.label }}{{ form.university(class_='form-control reg-select') }}

                        </div>
```

Error is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f865b91125ce413976b9002ed29bd7da)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use some smart IDE...I personally would prefer PyCharm. There must be some coding convention defined in your IDE so set it to UTF-8 and the code will work fine. If the issue was related to the whole data in template it could had been issue with UTF-8 but in your case you are copy pasting code from multiple different sources. So your code editor isn't able to identify exact character set. There is no other rational explanation for you issue.

Answer (score 0):

try encoding university.label as using 'utf-8' in the template.

```
 {{ form.university.label.encode('utf-8) }}
```

Comment: I already tried with this it says "'wtforms.fields.core.Label object' has no attribute 'encode'".